# adding debounce to Subject in rxjs/Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to create an events service, with the following code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export interface IPosition {
    x:number
    y:number
}

export interface IPositionEvent {
    id: string
    position: IPosition
}

@Injectable()
export class ModelEventsService {
    position$:Subject<IPositionEvent>;

    constructor() {
        this.position$ = new Subject().debounce(500);
    }

}
```

however, typescript generates the following error

> ERROR in /src/model-events.service.ts (20,49): Argument of type '500'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) =>
>   SubscribableOrPromise'.)

I've googled around, and whilst there are some solutions, most of them seem to apply to http and such, and I just can't understand *what exactly* the problem is.

Apparently I need to cast *something*, but I can't find the right syntax to do so

If I remove the `.debounce(500)` then the service works as expected and emits the events

Would appreciate any thoughts, ideas or help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the [`debounce` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounce) when it appears you should be using the [`debounceTime` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime).

`debounce` takes a selector function - mentioned in the error - and `debounceTime` takes a timeout duration in milliseconds.